# Getting a BQError while fetching the mail wise status in Google Cloud Function by using Sendgrid event webhook and storing it in Google Bigquery table

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions, webhooks, sendgrid

I am trying to fetch the individual mail wise status data(i.e whether a mail got delivered or bounced or read etc) by using the Sendgrid event webhook and want to store it in Google Bigquery. For this, I am using Google Cloud Function with nodeJS. But while running the function, I am getting a BQ Error stating "You must provide atleast 1 row to be inserted". But data is already there in Sendgrid.
I am pasting the input code below which is in index.js.

```html
const { BigQuery } = require("@google-cloud/bigquery");

const projectId = "Project_id";
const dataset = "Dataset_name";
const tableName = "Table_name";

//Initialize bigquery object
const bigQuery = new BigQuery({
  projectId: projectId,
});

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || "Hello World!";

  var timestamp = new Date().getTime() + "";
  var data = req.body;
  var rows = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    rows.push({
      hit_timestamp: timestamp,
      email: data[i]["email"],
      event: data[i]["event"],
      category: data[i]["category"] + "",
      event_id: data[i]["sg_event_id"],
      event_payload: JSON.stringify(data[i]),
    });
  }

  send_to_bq(rows);
  res.status(200).send(message);
};
function send_to_bq(rows) {
  bigQuery
    .dataset(dataset)
    .table(tableName)
    .insert(rows)
    .then((data) => {
      console.log(`Inserted rows : `, rows.length);
      //console.log(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      console.error("BQ ERROR:", err);
      console.error("BQ ERROR:", err.response.insertErrors[1].error);
    });
}
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code.  Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's [easy to read, copy, and search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/807126).  You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am modifying the question.

Comment: Have you confirmed (logged out) that `data` has an array of content and that `rows` is indeed populated before you run `send_to_bq`?

Comment: I printed the "data" but it was showing blank.

Comment: Moreover in package.json, I wrote this: 
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
        "@google-cloud/bigquery": "^2.1.0",
        "@sendgrid/mail":"^6.4.0"
        }
}

is it correct?
As the program is executing properly but I am not getting any data from Sendgrid.

Comment: Are you using Cloud Functions 1st gen or 2nd gen?

Comment: 1st generation.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. I deployed a similar 1st gen function myself (it just set up the `rows` array and then logged it) and it worked when I pressed the test event webhook button in my SendGrid account). I don't believe that SendGrid sends the event webhook with an empty array of data. Can you try logging both `req.body` and `req.rawBody` and seeing if there is a difference?

Comment: Am I using the correct fields/variables in the code to fetch the required data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. If you deployed the code as is and in the configuration of the cloud function selected "require authentication" the cloud function stops calls made to it that don't have permissions. You can either add permissions to your cloud function, redeploy the function allowing unauthenticated users to call it, or in the permissions for the cloud function add "all users" and set the role to "cloud function invoker". Hopefully, this helps.

Comment: I didn't do/change anything related to authentication. But I just changed the permission of that cloud function and added "all users" and set the role to "cloud function invoker". and it worked. Thanks for your help.