# SendGrid event export to GCP

Tags: node.js, google-bigquery, sendgrid

Basically, I'm trying to export the SendGrid event data to GCP storage using a cloud function in Node.js 16 using SendGrid's event Webhook functionality

I'm currently running (with example naming conventions);

```
const {BigQuery} = require('@google-cloud/bigquery');

const projectId = 'my_project';   
const dataset = 'my_dataset';
const tableName = 'sendgrid_events';

//Initialize bigquery object
const bigQuery = new BigQuery({
projectId: projectId
});

exports.helloWorld = (req, res) => {
 let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';

var timestamp = new Date().getTime()+'';
var data = req.body;
var rows = [];

for(var i=0; i< data.length; i++){
  rows.push({
    'hit_timestamp' : timestamp,
    'email':          data[i]['email'],
    'event':          data[i]['event'],
    'category':       data[i]['category']+ "",
    'event_id':       data[i]['sg_event_id'],
    'event_payload' : JSON.stringify(data[i]),
  });
}


send_to_bq(rows);
res.status(200).send(message);
};

function send_to_bq(rows){bigQuery
    .dataset(dataset)
    .table(tableName)
    .insert(rows) 
    .then((data) => {
  console.log(`Inserted rows : `, rows.length);
  //console.log(data);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error('BQ ERROR:', err);
    console.error('BQ ERROR:', err.response.insertErrors[1].error);

});


}
```

However, the data doesn't seem to pass into the table.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be [the same question as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473023/getting-a-bqerror-while-fetching-the-mail-wise-status-in-google-cloud-function-b). Are you the same person?

Comment: Oh wow, and asked on the same day. I am not the same person lol.

Comment: That's bizarre! Happy to try to help though. Are you using Cloud Functions 1st gen or 2nd gen?

Comment: 1st gen, I've done some troubleshooting and the function seems not to like it when there is no array to be sent

Comment: I can't see anything wrong with your code. I deployed a similar 1st gen function myself (it just set up the `rows` array and then logged it) and it worked when I pressed the test event webhook button in my SendGrid account). I don't believe that SendGrid sends the event webhook with an empty array of data. Can you try logging both `req.body` and `req.rawBody` and seeing if there is a difference?

Comment: hey @philnash, Thanks for your help. The problem was with the function being deployed requiring authentication and SendGrid not being included in the IAM big query permissions. I redeployed the function as unauthenticated to test and then added the necessary auth in after verifying. A little silly on my behalf. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Ah, glad you spotted this. I'll have to see if the other person's issue was the same too!

Comment: @BenWakelin I am trying to do something similar with Cloud Run. Do you know how the authentication is done in Sendgrid? AFAIK Cloud Run requires and identity token while Sendgrid uses and access token obtained via client credentials. Any ideas since you were able to set this up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is authentication, when deploying the cloud function setting it as unauthenticated means this boiler plate code works. However, if you require authentication then the permissions variable need to be added so google cloud can verify the data is being passed from the correct place.